# SQLite. Запись добавляется пустая

Tags: java, sqlite, sqlite3

Запрос в Java.
Добавляет пустую запись. Дебагер показывает, что объект передается правильно и данные есть, значит что проблема в запросе. Но он тоже выполняется, только не добавляет данные. Помогите.

```
  public void addToLibrary(Library library) {
    String tableChoise=null;
    if(library instanceof Book){
        tableChoise="Book";
    }else if(library instanceof Magazine){
        tableChoise="Magazine";
    }else if(library instanceof Newspaper){
        tableChoise="Newspaper";
    }
    try (PreparedStatement statement = this.connection.prepareStatement(
            "INSERT INTO "+tableChoise+" (`name`, `author`, `publisher`, `datePublisher`, `cost`, `purchasing`, `isGet`) " +
                    "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
        statement.setObject(1, library.name);
        statement.setObject(2, library.author);
        statement.setObject(3, library.publisher);
        statement.setObject(4, library.datePublish);
        statement.setObject(5, library.cost);
        statement.setObject(6, library.purchasing);
        statement.setObject(7, false);
        statement.execute();
        System.out.println("Added");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А посмотреть запрос после передачи параметров, непосредственно перед `statement.execute();`? Или переданный серверу запрос в General log - это ещё лучше.

Comment: Это база находящаяся в папке с проектом, обычный файл.
По запросу проверил, все значения есть

Answer (score 0):

В случаи, когда вы точно знаете, что запрос будет обновлять данные, следует использовать `statement.executeUpdate();`.